# PowerShell for-each cleanup

Tags: powershell

I know PowerShell is up to v5, but as I am new to PowerShell, I've been looking through Stack Overflow to generate the script I have. I've found that I need a generic non-version specific way of accomplishing this process...

Here is the issue - Step 1 - I'm pulling application installation locations information from the registry and am using a temporary file to house the results.

```
dir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\companyname" | Get-ItemProperty | Select installdir | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-Installs.txt"
```

This provides me a list of installation directories for the company's software that is installed on a particular machine. I then want to take these results, append *.config to each line, as well as taking these results and appending *.xml to each line, and output to a new text file.

The input for the process would be the contents of the initial results file, and the output file should have each line listed in the first results, added to the final results file, once appended with *.xml, and once appended with *.config.

The net effect I am looking for is the creation of a @file for a 7z command.  I am attempting this by using the following -

```
(Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-Installs.txt") -replace '\S+$','$&*.config' | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-config.txt" -Encoding utf8
(Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-Installs.txt") -replace '\S+$','$&*.xml' | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-config.txt" -Append -Encoding utf8
```

However, I'm only getting one line that has *.xml and one line that has *.config appended -

[image: Get-Content Output]

After getting this far, I'm thinking that some for-each loop is needed, but I'm not getting anywhere with what I have tried adapting from here. I'm looking now for some way to combine the three lines into one function, if that is possible, and eliminate the temporary file step in the first command, by reading and outputting in the same step. This would also need to remove the "installdir" and "----------" lines from the output.  Anyone have some ideas and maybe examples?

Comment: I removed the XML tag, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with working with XML. The fact you want to append the `.xml` extension to a filename does not make this about XML. Please read the description of tags instead of just tag spamming with things that sound familiar to you. Tags have specific meaning and relevance here.

Answer (score 1):

Taken your above command `dir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\companyname" | Get-ItemProperty | Select installdir | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\KDI-Admin\Export\$env:COMPUTERNAME-SC-Installs.txt"` you could put the result of your query into a variable `$result`:

```
$result = dir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\microsoft" | Get-ItemProperty | Select installdir;
```

From there you can easily loop through the array, skipping empty ones and process the rest of it:

```
foreach($path in $result.installdir) 
{ 
    # skip empty paths
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($path)) { continue; } 

    # now do your processing ...    
    $path; 
}
```

Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: What shall it be, `$path` or `$line` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings sorry - I meant `$path` but started writing `$line` and then changed my mind inbetween. thanks for spotting it. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that didn't work - while I was able to get $result to show the lines pulled from the registry, they weren't writing to the file, or "looping" thru the results and adding the two extensions I wanted added to the output file to be used by 7z as an @listfile.

Comment: Actually, I've gone further with it - it WAS exactly what I was looking for!  Took some time to run parts of the script, and finally was able to create my @listfile.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: very good! if it was what you were looking for, you might wanto to mark it as an accepted answer so other can profit from it too.